# Reading from database and passing to JavaScript in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Completely new to Python and Flask. Trying to read from database and pass the data to Javascript. Pulling my hair out trying to get it working, as I assume it's something small

In my python script I have:

```
@app.route('/report')
def test():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select * from emails where id=1')
    emails = cur.fetchall()
    print emails
    return render_template('report.html', name=links, emails=emails)
```

and then in my javascript I have:

```
{% for entry in emails %}
    var getEmail = {{entry.1}}
    window.alert(getEmail);
    emailArray.push(getEmail)
{% endfor %}
```

print emails is outputting `[(1, u'e')]`, which is correct, but the `window.alert` is giving me "undefined". If I change it to `var getEmail = {{entry.0}}` it gives me the correct ID value from the database. Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating:

```
var getEmail = e;
```

which is not working since `e` is undefined.

You want to quote your variables; use the [`tojson` filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#standard-filters) which comes with Flask, together with `safe` (to keep from quoting the `"` quotes generated):

```
var getEmail = {{ entry.1|tojson|safe }};
```

which will generate valid JSON, which is a subset of Javascript. Now your line will read:

```
var getEmail = "e";
```

Alternatively, set the `emailArray` list in one go (no loop over `emails` required) with:

```
var emailArray = {{ emails|map(attribute=1)|list|tojson|safe }};
```

which would take your `emails` list, select the 2nd element of each tuple, and output the resulting list as a JSON list, resulting in:

```
var emailArray = ["e"];
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks so much. Am I correct in saying that this doesn't apply to getting integer values? I was using pretty much the exact same code in a different spot to pull an integer value from my database and it worked fine, or should I use the tojson regardless of the datatype I'm retrieving?

Comment: @Killian: it so happens that the representation of integers is the same in both Python and Javascript, and that the *string* version of integers looks exactly like the literal value of an integer. In other words `"1"` in a template looks exactly like `1`, which is fine for JavaScript. For strings this doesn't work, you need those quotes. Best bet is to just use `tojson` everywhere you need set JavaScript literals.